# Class with a deleted copy constructor can be still copied?

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I have a simple function:
`void foo(atomic<int> a) { }`

It occurs that I can call `foo()` in this way:
`foo({ });`
but I can't do it in a such way:
`foo(atomic<int>{ });` due to an error message `copy constructor is a deleted function`. I have compiled with C++14.

1. What constructor is called in the first way: create constructor or move constructor?
2. Why in the second way is not called for example a move constructor?
3. These two calls of `foo()` compiles fine with C++17 - why?

Comment: What’s your compiler?

Comment: You could have passed the second argument as `std::move(atomic<int>{ })`, this should have forced the call of move constructor.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan - There is no move constructor. A user declared copy constructor (even a deleted one) doesn't allow an implicit generation of a move c'tor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `foo({ });`, the parameter is [copy list-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). As the result it's initialized by the default constructor of `std::atomic`.

In `foo(atomic<int>{ });`, the parameter is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the temporary `std::atomic` (i.e. `atomic<int>{ }`). Before C++17 even the copy/move operation might be elided the copy/move constructor still has to be present and accessible. Since C++17 this is not required again because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), it's guaranteed that the parameter is initialized by the default constructor of `std::atomic` directly.

> First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17)

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible: (since C++17)